# How is it possible that the jQuery works on Chrome console, but does not itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, overlays

I would like to make a overlay when the uses make hover event on a link.
This part ok, the overlay created and everything fine.
But I also would like to remove this overlay, when user click (or hover) for it, and this part create a strange bug.
I try clicking for the overlay and its dosen't close, nothing happening, but if you paste script  to the chrome console, this working fine.
Js, first part, add script:

```
  var overlay = jQuery('<div class="overlay"> </div>');
      $("#link-'.$myqlVideoID.'").hover(function() {
                 $("#hover-").attr("src","http://youtube.com/embed/'.$myqlVideoID.'?autoplay=1");
                 $(".drop-target").css("background-color","#070707");
                 $(".drop-target").css("padding","11px");
                 $(".drop-target").css("margin-bottom","16px");
                 $(".drop-target").show().fadeIn("3000");
                  overlay.appendTo(document.body)
           });
```

And the second part, remove overlay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overlay").click(function() {
      $("#hover-").removeAttr("src");
      $(".drop-target").hide().fadeOut("3000");
      $(".overlay").remove();
      console.log("clicked");
    });
  });
```

My site is where you can see the bug:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/search/
Just search something and scroll down to "Cimkék"

Comment: Well first things first onload your overlay is already covering your page...and your links and everything else.

Comment: We need to see the HTML and CSS as well. The information for your question must be **in** the question, not just linked. External links have a habit of changing over time, making the question useless to others in the future. If the question cannot be answered without using the link, it doesn't belong on SO in its current form.

Comment: use .on('click' , , )  and .on('hover' , , )    instead of .click() and .hover()

Comment: where exactly you have defined  overlay of  overlay.appendTo(document.body).

Comment: So what can I do?
Make css() function when hover event created?

Comment: @SuchitKumar You're right I missed out this definition sorry I fixit now

Comment: What?
Why I hve two votedown?

Comment: I'd suggest doing most of the presentational logic in the css,  and use the javascript (jQuery) for events and applying the css defined styles by changing classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delegating the event on the overlay by writing the following: 
`$(document).on('click', '.overlay',  function ()  {
    //The rest of your code 
}) ;`

And same for the rest of your event handlers.

The reason for this is that the element `overlay` is being added dynamically,  and the script doesn't know about it at the moment when it's being instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. I made an update above.  The idea is that you're clicking an overlay, not the document, and this way you should be delegating the event to the overlay element

Comment: Thx for edit!
Please chancge the id to class (the page not le me this little modification)